# Send finger.fingerID to Bluetooth

Tags: arduino

I'm able to send some characters in blue tooth to my android device.
But after scanning my finger and send the finger.fingerID value to android device,
Only a special character was sent.
So it came to me that the value is Integer and tried to convert it to character but still getting some error.
When I run my code here, I immediately getting back to void setup();

```
int getFingerprintIDez() {
  uint8_t p = finger.getImage();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  p = finger.image2Tz();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  p = finger.fingerFastSearch();
  if (p != FINGERPRINT_OK)  return -1;

  // found a match!


  Serial.print("Found ID #"); Serial.print(finger.fingerID); 
  Serial.print(" with confidence of "); Serial.println(finger.confidence);  


  String toStr;
  char toChar[2];
  toStr=String(finger.fingerID);  
  toStr.toCharArray(toChar, toStr.length());
  BTSerial.write(toChar);
  Serial.print(toChar); 
  return finger.fingerID; 
}
```

Comment: What is "some error"?

Answer (score 0):

Your `toChar` buffer is too small for a string that could possibly be 5 characters long. You should allocate 10 bytes instead, more than enough to hold any result.

`toCharArray` does not null-terminate the string so even if `write()` accepts null-terminated strings alone (it doesn't), it would run off the end of the string looking for a null. `write()` accepts either a single character or a pointer to a char array *and* the number of characters to be written.

You don't need to go through all this hassle; merely call:

```
BT.print(finger.fingerID);
```

And the built-in `Print` class will handle the conversion messiness for you.